Why is this part of my code not adding the new columns to my data frame?
I have 13 datasets that are in .XPT format called data2010, data2011, data2012.. data2022. These are the BRFSS datasets from the CDC website. I have been trying to add three new columns to each of my dataframes called TREAT, POST and YEAR and initialise them to some value. This is a short snippet of my code
library(dplyr)

datasets <- list(data2010, data2011, data2012, data2013, data2014, data2015,
                 data2016, data2017, data2018, data2019, data2020, data2021, data2022)

for(i in 1:length(datasets)) {
  datasets[[i]] <- datasets[[i]] %>%
    mutate(TREAT = 0, POST = 0, YEAR = i + 2009)
}


I have ran this multiple times to no avail. I can see on the environment pane in RStudio that the number of columns do not increase and when I use the console to check (by running data2017$POST, I get the following response
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `POST`.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Your loop is updating the data frames in the list and not the original ones.
See the below example.
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(x=5:10, y=5:10)

datasets <- list(N1=df1, N2=df2)

for(i in 1:length(datasets)) {
   datasets[[i]] <- datasets[[i]] %>%
      mutate(newcol = i+100)
}

datasets$N1
#   x y newcol
# 1 1 1    101
# 2 2 2    101
# 3 3 3    101

df1
# x y
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3


So how do I go about this issue? Can I run a loop that would directly alter the actual data?

You really don't want to do that!  It is best to load the data frames into the list and just keep them there.  It is much more convenient to work with the elements in a list than a dozen variables in the global environment.  If you must, see the get() and assign() functions.

You can set the names of your list (datasets) and then use them when assigning within your for loop.
datasets <- setNames(list(iris, mtcars), 
                    c('iris', 'mtcars'))

lapply(datasets, head, n=3)
$iris
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

$mtcars
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1


for(i in 1:length(datasets)) {
  datasets[[i]] <- datasets[[i]] %>%
    mutate(TREAT = 0, POST = 0, YEAR = i + 2009)

  # Add the following line
  assign(names(datasets[i]), datasets[[i]])
}

head(iris, 3)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species TREAT POST YEAR
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     0    0 2010
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     0    0 2010
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     0    0 2010

head(mtcars, 3)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb TREAT POST YEAR
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     0    0 2011
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     0    0 2011
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     0    0 2011

You could also use list2env(datasets, .GlobalEnv) after the for loop (as mentioned by @DarrenTsai) instead of assigning the individual elements inside the loop, but the list must be named.

You can also use list2env(datasets, .GlobalEnv)
